# 100% width div with child span won't right align

Tags: html, css, alignment

Given [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/UNxyw/), I want my menu to be at the right edge of the overall "card", but for some reason it won't work.  I've tried a couple different methods (margins, right: 0, float) but they either don't work or I lose the background color of the parent div (in the case of float where it basically collapses the parent div).

Here is my current HTML and CSS, as seen in the fiddle.

```
<div class="server">
    <div class="name">Server01</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <span class="items">
            <span>Menu01</span>
            <span>Menu02</span>
            <span>Menu03</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>

.server {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #686868;
}

.name {
    font-size: large;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
    cursor: default;
}

.menu {
    font-size: small;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
}
.menu .items span {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.menu .items {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I would really suggest using a css grid system like [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/grid.php) or [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), rather than doing this from scratch. But yes you can text-align inline elements, provided that the rule is applied to the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a text-align on a span EDIT: if you don't specify the width.

If you move to the .menu it works

```
.menu {
    font-size: small;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
       text-align: right;
}

.menu .items {
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;

    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you apply `text-align:right` to a `<span />` element? If the element has a specific width... http://jsfiddle.net/UNxyw/1/

Comment: No the way he did it.

Comment: Gotcha, so you are referring specifically to the inner-most `<span />` elements, which do not have a specific width set.

Answer (score 2):

You have made your `<span />` element have `width:100%` so you will need to align the text to the right instead of float the box. Floating the box only works if there is space to float-into, but since your box is 100% wide, there's not space into which it can move. Floating would work if you didn't specify a width, and to keep the background color you'd have to wrap the element in another element and give the new parent element the background color.

Here's an updated version of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UNxyw/1/

I only applied `text-align:right` to the `.menu` element.